# LVL testing not working. Clear cache

Tags: android, android-lvl

I'm testing LVL in my app for first time. After reading carefully [the dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/licensing/index.html), I implement the default sample using `ServerManagedPolicy` with few changes and uploaded as a draft to my developer account.
The fist time I ran my app I could see it was verifying the license (it delayed few secons and indeterminate progress showing). The callback was `LICENSED`. Perfect up to here.

But then I changed test response (in Edit Profile in my developer account) and next times I ran it, inmediately shows LICENSED without conecting and checking, like if it was reading from cache.

(I'm testing in a physical device and which has 2 google accounts (the developer one and other.)

Is there a way to clear this cache?
Or I'm doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Another way is to use StrictPolicy for testing the results of the license check, so that no license results are cached.

Just replace the line:

```
mChecker = new LicenseChecker( this, new ServerManagedPolicy( this,
  new AESObfuscator( SALT, getPackageName(), deviceId ) ), BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY );
```

with:

```
mChecker = new LicenseChecker( this, new StrictPolicy(), BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY );
```

Comment: Thanks, finally I added my other account for testing and response changed properly.

Answer (score 5):

Changing the salt should help to refresh a license response.